# Как правильно говорить: на сковороде или в сковороде?

Tags: лексика, предлоги

Answer (score 3):

Ответ надо искать в значении слова. Сковородка — это мелкая, с загнутыми краями, круглая металлическая посуда для жаренья. То есть фактически это плоский лист металла с загнутыми краями. А кладём мы НА плоские поверхности, а не В. Правильно — на сковороде.

Answer (score 2):

*На сковороде - в сковороде* - это синонимичные конструкции.
При выборе предлога в синонимических конструкциях учитывается различие в смысловых и стилистических оттенках между ними. Ср.: в клочки – на клочки (разорвать).Первое сочетание имеет значение «разорвать на мелкие части, не поддающиеся счету», второе – «разорвать на части, поддающиеся счету». "Грамота.ру" приводит оба примера: *жаренная на сковороде картошка*  и *жарить картошку в сковороде вок*.Шире эту тему Вы можете изучить здесь: [УПРАВЛЕНИЕ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm), §199. Выбор предлога.

Answer (score 1):

Приходится слышать "на сковороде". Наверное, это правильно, т.к. предлогу НА соответствует предлог С(СО): взять со сковороды. Предлогу В соответствует предлог ИЗ: положить в кастрюлю - вынуть из кастрюли.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос не имеет прямого решения в сфере филологии. 
Самый простой случай: "налить В сковороду масла" (подразумевается сковорода с высоким бортиком), "тушить В сковороде" и проч. Но "положить мясо на сковороду", "жарить на сковороде" и проч. Зависит от того, какую функцию выполнять или какую часть сковороды считать рабочей.